# Avoiding MS Graph Throttling

Tags: azure, sharepoint

I have an MS Graph call to a SharePoint Online site.  Throttling has become an issue and I am trying to implement some suggestions I found in various videos to avoid the throttling.  I intend to slow down the calls or delay them when the warning number starts to get high.  Unfortunately I have been unable to find this value.  It is supposedly in a response header, but GraphServiceClient has no such header.  Here is the code I have tried.

```
        public string? FindFolder(string folderName)
        {
            var graphClient = _getGraphClientFunction();

            var task = graphClient
                .Drives[_sharePointAssessmentsDriveId]
                .Items["root"]
                .Children
                .GetAsync(requestConfiguration =>
                {
                    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Filter = $"name eq '{folderName}'";
                    requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("Rate-limit", "remaining");
                });
            task.Wait();
//Where is the header with the Rate-limit result?
            return task.Result.Value.SingleOrDefault(e => e.Folder != null)?.Id;
        }
```

Where can I find the Rate-limit remaining header.  I understand that it may not appear until a certain threshold is reached.

After adding the requestConfiguration.Headers.Add("Rate-limit", "remaining"); line I expected a header element to appear in the task.Result.